# Digital multimeter is reading erratic resistance ohm values

Tags: multimeter, ohmmeter

I have not come across this issue before in searches on this forum and searches on Google. I wonder if anyone else has come across it.

My digital multimeter is unable to measure ohms. I'm just trying to read a simple single 100R resistor but the readings fluctuate.

I took the leads out and replaced, but still have the same problem.

I took out the leads completely, and the multimeter still shows a reading even when open circuit.

Can this be fixed or do I have to buy another one?

[image: ghost resistance]

Also other photos and a video at : https://i.stack.imgur.com/C41Ui.jpg

Thanks in advance for your guidance.

Comment: Check the battery, check the leads contacts (both ends), and the continutity in the middle of the leads (gentle pulling and twisting), before you bin it and buy a new one.

Comment: Is it possible it got wet?

Comment: Neil_UK Yeah I've changed the leads and then I thought of unplugging it completely (which I've done as per pic). The reading should say 1. but it is giving me a kOhm reading which shouldn't be the case.
Spehro It hasn't got wet I think, unless through humidity. I have measured AC with it but I don't think it's blown or anything. I've already opened it to inspect if any solder points were obviously cracked but none of that as far as I noticed.

Answer (score 1):

Low or dead battery is the common cause. The internal voltage reference is not very stabile when the battery gets below a certain level (exact value depends on the exact meter used).  In any case, battery is the issue about 90% of the time. Other issues can be broken test leads or poor connections in the banana jacks in the meter.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the comments. All the replies seem to say the battery. I use a rechargeable battery in the multimeter, 9V Ni-MH. Do you think the rechargable battery could be the issue? I don't have a spare standard one at the moment or I would verify it now.

Comment: @Azrudi:  You should use the type of batttery the meter is designed to use.  I think an NiMH "9V" battery's maximum voltage is somewhat below 9 volts.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the meter's battery while powering the meter.

- Select DC volts.
- Touch the V lead to each battery terminal in turn.
- Subtract the readings from each other to get the total battery voltage.

This works because the COM voltage is somewhere around midway between the supply voltage.

---

While you have it open take the PCB out and examine and clean the multipole switch wiper contacts and gold plated PCB contacts.

[image]

*Figure 1. The contacts arrangement will be similar to this. Image source: [Engineers Garage](https://www.engineersgarage.com/insight-how-digital-multimeter-works/) (without any apostrophes!)*.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Is the multipole switch wiper the round bits of contact when you select what mode the multimeter should go to?

That's a great tip about using the multimeter itself to test its battery. The battery is newly charged, but this is a useful tip.

Comment: It will be something like https://www.engineersgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/LCD-PCB-Rotary-Knob-Switch.jpg. See the whole article here: https://www.engineersgarage.com/insight-how-digital-multimeter-works/.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I saw this part when I was opening it. I've cleaned it too but I'll clean it again.